# Activemq Artemis Console Certificate Authentication

Tags: jaas, hawtio, activemq-artemis

I am trying to setup the built in hawt.io console to authenticate users based off of certificates instead of username and password. I've looked around and can't find much info on how to go about doing this. The best I found was this person [asking the same question](http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/Client-certificate-login-to-management-console-td4738680.html) which pretty much allowed me to get the same spot they are in.

Just to reiterate I am not trying to setup certificate authentication for the queues (I already have that working), but rather the management console that runs with the broker.

Any advice on how to do this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Certificate-based authentication is not yet supported from Hawtio side as well. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/hawtio/ePDMUKWbYco https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2469 Please keep an eye on it so you can see when it's implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Tadayoshi Sato. Not yet supported but there is an open ticket:

https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/issues/2469

Answer (score 1):

The management console is served by an embedded instance of [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/). Therefore, if you want to configure the management console for certificate based authentication you'll need to find out if Jetty itself supports this functionality. I tend to doubt that Jetty supports certificate based authentication because I have looked for this myself and I've not found anything. Looking at [their JAAS code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-jaas/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/jaas) I see no evidence that they are even attempting to handle this use-case. Google searches have only turned up SSL/TLS configuration information, not actual JAAS auth details.